# Flexbox horizontal align text link with image inline

Tags: css, flexbox

I want couple of rows, across the entire height of the page. Image with text in each rows on the same line. My code throws the image to the left and the text on a new line in the middle.

How to put an image with a link inside the row on one line centered and also align the image with the link vertically in the center of the row?

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box item1"><img src="item1.jpg"><a href="item1.html">item1</a></div>
    <div class="box item2"><img src="item1.jpg"><a href="item1.html">item1</a></div>
    <div class="box item3"><img src="item1.jpg"><a href="item1.html">item1</a></div>
    <div class="box item4"><img src="item1.jpg"><a href="item1.html">item1</a></div>
    <div class="box item5"><img src="item1.jpg"><a href="item1.html">item1</a></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
.container {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    .box {
        text-align: center;
        color: black;       
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .box img {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
    }           
    .item1 {
        background-color: white;
        height: 25%;
    }   
    .item2 {
        background-color: silver;
        height: 25%;
    }
    .item3 {
        background-color: white;
        height: 25%;
    }
    .item4 {
        background-color: silver;
        height: 25%;
    }
    .item5 {
        background-color: white;
        height: 25%;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change `flex-direction` because it should be `row` and it is set by default and you don't need `text-align: center` here because `justify-content` does the same thing.

Note: Your CSS rules were nested. In browser these kind of nested CSS don't work. You need a pre-processor to process those first and then apply the generated CSS. I have corrected that as well.

```
.box{
    /* text-align: center; */           
    /* flex-direction: column; */            
            
    /* added codes */
    align-items: center; /* For vertically centering the image and the link */
}

.box img {
    /* added code */
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
.container {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;                    
}

.box{
    /* text-align: center; */
    color: black;
    display: flex;
    /* flex-direction: column; */
    justify-content: center;

    /* added codes */
    align-items: center;
}

.box img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    /*justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;*/

    /* added code */
    margin-right: 10px;
} 

.item1 {
    background-color: white;
    height: 25%;
}  

.item2 {
    background-color: silver;
    height: 25%;
}

.item3 {
    background-color: white;
    height: 25%;
}

.item4 {
    background-color: silver;
    height: 25%;
}

.item5 {
    background-color: white;
    height: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box item1"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1"><a href="item1.html">item1</a></div>
    <div class="box item2"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=2"><a href="item1.html">item1</a></div>
    <div class="box item3"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=3"><a href="item1.html">item1</a></div>
    <div class="box item4"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=4"><a href="item1.html">item1</a></div>
    <div class="box item5"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=5"><a href="item1.html">item1</a></div>
</div>
```